# Placing bar chart labels on the upper and lower frame axes

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling, charts

In the bar chart (with negative values)

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, -{4, 5, 6}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"r1", "r2"}, Above], 
   Placed[{"c1", "c2", "c2"}, Below]}]
```

[image]

the bar and group labels can be placed above and below the bars.

How can I place the bar and group labels on the upper and lower frame axes like in the paired bar chart

```
PairedBarChart[{Range[4], Range[4]/2}, {Range[4], Range[4]/2}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"pair1", "pair2"}, Above], 
   Placed[{"g1", "g2"}, "LeftAxis"], 
   Placed[{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, "RightAxis"]}]
```

[image]

where the labels are placed to the left and right axis by using `Placed[{"g1", "g2"}, "LeftAxis"]` and `Placed[{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, "RightAxis"]`? Unfortunately, this doesn't work with `BarChart` and "TopAxis" nor "BottomAxis".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** In versions 11.3+, using `Callout` instead of `Placed` gives the desired result:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, -{4, 5, 6}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Callout[{"r1", "r2"}, Above], 
   Placed[{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, Axis]}]
```

[image]

Use `Callout[{"r1", "r2"}, Above, Appearance -> None]` to get

[image]

**Note:** In version 12.1 we get the same output with an error message. You can wrap `BarChart` with `Quiet` to suppress the message.

**Original answer:**

Post-processing to account for `BarSpacing` settings when placing bar labels on frameticks (as in @bensheperd's answer),

```
dta = {{1, 2, 3}, -{4, 5, 6}};
bc = BarChart[dta, BarSpacing -> {.3, .6}, ImageSize -> 450,
ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"r1", "r2"}, Axis], Placed[{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, Above]}];
tks = Riffle[GatherBy[ Cases[bc, 
  Text[t_, Offset[{_, _}, {x_, y_}] | {x_, y_}, ___] :> {x, ToString@t}, {0, Infinity}],
  StringTake[Last[#], 1] &],
  {Automatic, Automatic}];
bc2 = BarChart[dta, BarSpacing-> {.3, .6}, ImageSize ->450,Frame-> True, FrameTicks -> tks];
Row[{bc, bc2}]
```

[image]

Comment: In the above Barchart, `Placed[{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, Axis]}]` is used to give the same labels for elements under both `r1` and `r2`. How do you give different labels for the group called `r2` like {"z1", "z2", "z3"}?

Answer (score 8):

This first solution is not exactly what you're looking for, but it gets close:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, -{4, 5, 6}}, 
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"r1", "r2"}, {.5, 2}], 
  Placed[{"c1", "c2", "c2"}, Axis]}]
```

[image]

To get the correct representation you need to tweak a bit some values:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, -{4, 5, 6}}, 
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"r1", "r2"}, {.5, 2}], 
  Placed[{"c1", "c2", "c2"}, {{0, 0}, {-2.2, 11}}]}]
```

[image]

**Update**

If you also need the axes on top and on bottom of the figure, you might try this approach (similar to the solution provided by benshepherd):

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, -{4, 5, 6}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {Transpose[{Range[.7, 6.3, (6.3 - .7)/5], {"c1", "c2", 
  "c3", "c1", "c2", "c3"}}], 
  Automatic, {{.7 + (6.3 - .7)/5, "r1"}, {6.3 - (6.3 - .7)/5, "r2"}},
  Automatic}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to print axes like in the PairedBarChart?

Comment: Please, see update.

Comment: Note, that this won't work for `BoxWhiskerChart`, as it seems to ignore `FrameTicks` specifications.

Answer (score 5):

No, there doesn't appear to be a valid argument for `Placed` - Mathematica wants to place your label relative to the bar.

To get labels on the axes, I think you'd have to use `FrameTicks`:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, -{4, 5, 6}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
   Transpose@{Range@6, {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c1", "c2", "c3"}}, 
   Automatic}, Frame -> True]
```